# Angular $sce.trustAsHtml with Arabic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arabic

Angular 1.4

I have the following function used by an `ng-repeat` that works nice, the html is rendered correctly.

```
$scope.TrustDangerousSnippet = function (customer) {
    var textwithhtml = customer.SomeHtmlValue;
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(textwithhtml);
};
```

However, if the `div` the `ng-repeat` is on has direction set to `LTR` (Arabic), then $sce.trustAsHtml(textwithhtml); renders the HTML backwards. `</p>` is rendered `<p/>` and so appears in the display incorrectly.

Is this a bug or is there a workaround to use `trustAsHtml` with `ltr` languages?